# Error: The loader in .css didn't return a string in Angular 12.1.1

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

I have created a new project but whenever I am compiling getting the 2 below error messages:

> Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:/Users/Avishek/Documents/practice/frontend/src/app/pages/admin/authentication/authentication.component.css' in 'C:\Users\Avishek\Documents\practice\frontend'

and

> Error: The loader "C:/Users/Avishek/Documents/practice/frontend/src/app/pages/admin/authentication/authentication.component.css" didn't return a string.

I have never faced this type of issue before even few days back I created a project with the same angular version still did not get. Below is my `tsconfig.json` & `package.json` files respectively.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@directive/*": ["src/app/core/directives/*"],
      "@guard/*": ["src/app/core/guards/*"],
      "@interceptor/*": ["src/app/core/interceptors/*"],
      "@pipe/*": ["src/app/core/pipes/*"],
      "@service/*": ["src/app/core/services/*"],
      "@custom-validator/*": ["src/app/core/validators/*"],
      "@model/*": ["src/app/core/models/*"],
      "@store/*": ["src/app/core/store/*"],
      "@feature/*": ["src/app/features/*"],
      "@page/*": ["src/app/pages/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["src/app/shared/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.7.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.2"
  }
}
```

Please help out what type of issue is this and how can I solve it.

Comment: I'm getting the same error for `app.component.css`. My application doesn't even have an `app.component.css` as I'm using `scss` files instead.

Answer (score 42):

The problem in my case was that my project was configured to use `scss` files but that I had copied some code from a sample that used `css` files. So in one of my components I had:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

The `css` file in the stypeUrls property was the cause of the error.

Comment: Yah I found that but even though I solved it still it got me an error. How I fixed is a real funny thing that I created a new project with CSS as my styling format and then just put my app folder in it. And BOOM every thing is working fine now .

Comment: I misspelled the name of one of the files. *facepalm*. Thanks for making me look at it again.

Comment: This is the error I get when the styleUrls is styleUrls: [''],

Comment: My project uses css configuration only. Still I'm getting above error. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 5):

Just misspelling your styleUrls

use scss instead of css

[image]

Comment: great, this solved my same problem

Answer (score 4):

My project location was setup in a folder that had special character in the path.
Hence the angular project build could not reach the .css file.
The following is the before and after I altered the folder path

```
before  G:\Projects\C#\WebAPIProject\FrontEnd\AngularUI 
after   G:\Projects\CSharp\WebAPIProject\FrontEnd\AngularUI
```

I figured this out, when I tried to click the file path that was provided in the terminal window as the one that was causing the error and then click the prompt that says 'open file in editor'. This didn't open the file in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

If your using SCSS in your project change your  styleUrls from:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './hero-detail.component.css' ] //Notice
})
```

To:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './hero-detail.component.scss' ] //Notice
})
```

That worked for my project

Answer (score 1):

i solved this problem by checking the path pricesily because i was working on projects and there were many files , so my path was needing an additional /..
/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For Me I already dont have scss or CSS file in my folder so I just remooved the line
styleUrls: [ './hero-detail.component.scss' ]

It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Just change the directory in the templateUrl  to yourcomponent.html and write html in that directory

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).