# Angular14 new project doesn't want to start - app.component.css issue

Tags: angular, angularjs, visual-studio-code

Environment :

- Windows 10
- Node - v16.18.1
- npm - 8.19.2
- AngularJS - 14.2.10

[image]

I did create new project using

```
ng new client
```

after I opened location with new project and tried to start it.

```
cd client
ng serve
```

Unfortunately, the application showed an error:

> Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'O:/Sources/C#/testAngular/client/src/app/app.component.css?ngResource' in 'O:\Sources\C#\testAngular\client'

> Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'O:\Sources\C#\testAngular\client\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=auto%3A&username=&password=&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=0&pathname=%2Fng-cli-ws&logging=info&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=false&live-reload=true' in 'O:\Sources\C#\testAngular\client'

> Error: The loader "O:/Sources/C#/testAngular/client/src/app/app.component.css" didn't return a string.

[image]

Everything was working last month and suddenly it stop building any angular projects. I can't understand what am I missing to make it working.

UPD: Solved.
I had an issue with file path. Angular/cli doesn't like symbols in the file path. I have moved the project into a folder without any symbols and it did work.

Comment: could you try upgrading the cli to 15 and try ng new?

Comment: I just updated **angular/cli** to **15.0.3** and result is the same.

Comment: Does your project contain an `app.component.css` file? 
If not, in your `app.component.ts` file, update the `styleUrls` to `styleUrls: [ './app.component.scss' ]` (replace `css` with `scss`) 
You might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69148615/error-the-loader-in-css-didnt-return-a-string-in-angular-12-1-1

Comment: I have created project using CSS option, not SCSS.