# Can't run the newly created Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I've just created an app, but I can't launch it.

Error: The loader “C:/C#/Angular/my-app/src/app/app.component.css” didn't return a string.

[image: Here is Terminal]

[image: Versions]

Trying to reinstall Angular,Node js but nothing helps...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: The loader in .css didn't return a string in Angular 12.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69148615/error-the-loader-in-css-didnt-return-a-string-in-angular-12-1-1)

Comment: I don't know but I don't like the `C#` directory. Can you try to create the project under a directory that does not contain the `#` character ?

Comment: Also, not all versions of Node are compatible with Angular. You might want to check this [compatibility matrix](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3). TLDR : try with Node 16.x or Node 18.10 and see if it helps. Tip : use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to handle several versions of Node installed concurrently

Comment: @RameshRajendran I just created the application, I didn't add any code elements

Comment: app.component.css is a default file. pls  check

Comment: Tried with Node 18.15.0 with same options as you (but under Ubuntu). It worked. So it might not be related to the version of Node after all

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I'm surpised. Removing the # from the folder name really helped me. Thank you!

Comment: @NazarNyrka If you have the patience, you can try to open a bug to the Angular team [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues) because I feel like this character should be authorized in a path but is probably interpreted as beginning of comments or an anchor in HTML. So either they will fix it or explain why it is forbidden, and/or put a clear error message :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm that I can reproduce the problem if I create the project under a directory that contains the `#` character and that the problem is fixed if I just create the same project under a directory that does not contain the `#` character.

So, the **temporary solution** is : create the project under another directory.

*I feel like* this character should be avoided in a path anyway but should still technically be authorized.

I opened a bug to the Angular team [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/24887) to see if this behavior is normal and will update the answer as soon as I get a response.

**EDIT** : This is a known issue that comes from webpack [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/16819)

Comment: you have a # character in your file directory? That just seems like a bad idea for numerous reasons. honestly I would stick with alpha-numerical for all folder names

Comment: @Rick totally agree. I used this character just to see if I could reproduce OP's problem and indicated in the answer that it is probably a bad idea